# Weatherproof stainable gap filler for rail to stile joint

Tags: wood, doors, wood-filler

I'm refinishing an entry door. There is a small gap between the bottom rail and the stile. (1/16" or less, I'd say.) I want to fill that gap to prevent water infiltration, but I'm concerned that, with the wrong filler, it will eventually open up again. Whatever filler I use, I want to be able to stain it.

What is the best solution for this sort of problem?

[image]

Comment: Whatever you use (and I personally think you should use nothing or clear caulk *after* it is finished) it will need to remain flexible or it will very likely crack and fall out. I don't know of any stainable product that remains flexible when cured.